# Using AVQueuePlayer to enforce/respect desired gaps between PlayItems

Tags: iphone, cocoa, avqueueplayer

Hi all I'm using `AVQueuePlayer` to play a sequence of media files (audio, video). I sometimes have `PlayItems` that are shorter than the durations I need i.e. I want a silence between some items. I have been considering trying to use some combination of `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval` `addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes` or running my own `NSTimer`.

It doesn't need to be super accurate + or - 1 Second is acceptable.
I'm wondering if there is any collective wisdom out there about these using these API calls to achieve this kind of functionality ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not observe the end of the items, and then, if necessary, start to play again only after a certain delay?

You start to observe the end of an `AVPlayerItem` like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playEnded) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:playerItem];
```

Then, in your `playEnded` method, you can decide how long you need to wait, and call another method to start play of the next item after a delay.

```
-(void)playEnded {
    [self performSelector:@selector(playNextItem) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and i think that would work. I was already observing that notification but since the content is not going to change after it's queued I figured it would be better to build a **AVMutableComposition**. That also allowed me to add a beep in between items. Seems to work well for my purposes though it ended up being complicated than your suggestion.